# Getting undefined when calling a method using event.target

Tags: javascript, events

Im sorry for the abstract title, but I dont know how to better explain what I'm dealing with here. So basically I want to create a method which will be used when adding an eventlistener in another method.

```
playerShips(obj) {
  let shipCounter = this.createCounter(obj.container);
  obj.element.addEventListener("click", this.addShipsEvent({
    counter: obj.counter,
    shipCounter: shipCounter
  }));
}

addShipsEvent(event, obj) {
    if ( event.target.getAttribute("class") === "cell" ) {
      event.target.classList.add("active");
      obj.counter += 1;
    } else {
      event.target.classList.remove("active");
      obj.counter -= 1;
    }     
}
```

When I run it I get the following error :TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined, which is reffering to `if ( event.target.getAttribute("class") === "cell" )`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try to console.log(event.target) inside addShipEvent to confirm event is the rightful target.

Comment: I get undefined when i console.log(event.target)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly because "addEventListener" expect an event listener as a second argument, but you are just executing "addShipsEvent" without returning any.
The solution is to simply return a closure.

```
addShipsEvent(obj) {
    return function(event) {
        if ( event.target.getAttribute("class") === "cell" ) {
          event.target.classList.add("active");
          obj.counter += 1;
        } else {
          event.target.classList.remove("active");
          obj.counter -= 1;
        }
    };
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I think binding should do the same. e.g. addEventListener("click", this.addShipsEvent.bind(this, {...})